# MS Access Form Load

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I have a form with two combo boxes and couple of buttons. One of the buttons (called "Roll Over") is for rolling over data from the previous year. When clicked it should be able to grab the data from the previous year and insert in the form for the next year.

I have written the code but it does not insert the data when clicked on the button instead it inserts the data after the form has been opened once.

For example: 
I click on "Roll Over" and then I click on a form, the form opens up but there is no data. I close the form. Click on "Roll Over" again. I open the form again and the data has been inserted.

I am not sure why it doesn't let me insert the data without the form being opened at least once.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
Form_1_Test.Text10 = DLookup("Legal_Name", "1_Test", "[Program_Name] = '" & Replace([Combo2], "'", "''") & "' And [BudgetYear] = " & ([Combo0] - 1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to re-query the form after inserting the data.  Add the following line at the end of your `MyButton_Click()` code (ie, after the code that inserts the new records):

```
Me.Requery
```

---

It may help to keep in mind that you are not inserting records "into the form".  Rather you are inserting the records into the underlying table(s) that your form is based on.

And while Access forms will automatically refresh changed data for loaded records*, they will not poll for the existence of newly created records.  You must force the form to do that via the form's `Requery` method.

* <sub>assuming you have not changed the default Recordset Type property from "Dynaset"</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it does not work. I typed Me.Requery under the code but nothing changed

Comment: You do realize that this line: `Form_1_Test.Text10 = DLookup("Legal_Name", "1_Test", "[Program_Name] = '" & Replace([Combo2], "'", "''") & "' And [BudgetYear] = " & ([Combo0] - 1))` is not actually inserting any data, correct?

Comment: is it not? But I thought, it is getting the value by using the "DLookup" function and then assigning that value to Text10?

Comment: The result of the DLookup function is being assigned to Text10, but **forms do not store data**.  You will need to use an "Append Query" (`INSERT INTO ...`) if you want to actually add data to one of your underlying tables.